# How to split last field of a full route

Tags: shell, awk

I have some files in different route like below:

```
./a/b/c/test.h
./d/e/f/g/h/abc1.c
./i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/hello.log
...
```

And I want to get only the file name of each one. That is: I want to get "**test.h**", "**abc1.c**", "**hello.log**".

As the deep of the route is uncertain, so maybe awk can't help my problem.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Yes, Thanks to all! basename is the exact command I want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `basename` command:

```
while read line
do
basename $line
done < "myfile"
```

Comment: I haven't heard the basename command, I will google about it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly want I want :-)

Answer (score 0):

`basename` is often the way to do this, but here is how you could do it in AWK:

```
filename=./i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/hello.log
echo "$filename" | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

another:

```
awk -v filename="$filename" 'BEGIN {len = split("/", filename, a); print a[len]}'
```

in pure Bash:

```
echo ${filename##*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' file_name
```